# change css for facebook comments box

Tags: css, facebook

I've been trying to add a different background color to the facebook comments box on my site. 
I've tried`'
and I've tried to add a  which wraps the code. But nothing seems to work.

How do I change the background color of the comments box?

Answer (score 0):

you may use the light theme and put the FBDIV inside another container..then change the background of container... of course you can't edit the css becouse the comment plugin loads inside an iframe... You can use FBML but it's deprecated.

Comment: Could you show me in code how to do this? I've tried to wrap the iframe in a div and it isn't working. My site is naiveartonline.com in mobile view. (For some reason it is fine on desktop view)